# Adding Tracking Details for Advanced Shipment Tracking Plugin From Order Notes

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, automation

I have a woocomerce site which is connected to UPS e-fulfillment and when they they ship out an order, the tracking number ends up getting updated to the order notes like in this example:

[image]

To put quite simply, UPS e-fulfillment is connecting to the woocomerce api and updating the order notes with the tracking number.
The thing I am trying to do is taking this order note and setting it as the tracking number within the Advanced Shipment Tracking plugin.

I don't know much about PHP but I sort of have an idea however to start out going about it but not 100% sure.
Below is the add_order_note function found in class-wc-order.php and the function ast_insert_tracking_number found in tracking-number.php of the AST plugin.

[image]
[image]

The way I am think about this is just calling the ast_insert_tracking_number function from the add_order_note function however I am not 100% sure how to go about doing that. Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code snippet in functions.php and let me know.

```
/*
* AST: get UPS Tracking number from order note
* 
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_rest_insert_order_note', 'action_woocommerce_rest_insert_order_note', 10, 3 );
function action_woocommerce_rest_insert_order_note( $note, $request, $true ) {
    //check if AST is active
    if ( !function_exists( 'ast_insert_tracking_number' ) ) return;
    
    //check if order note is for UPS
    if( strpos( $note->comment_content, '1Z' ) !== false ){
        
        $order_id = $request['order_id'];
        $status_shipped = 1;
        $tracking_number = $note->comment_content;
        $tracking_provider = 'UPS';
        
        ast_insert_tracking_number($order_id, $tracking_number, $tracking_provider, '', $status_shipped );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would normally be off topic, but I happen to have done something very similar recently, so I can share. The way I handled this was to hook into `wp_insert_comment` (order notes are added as comments), check whether the comment is an order note, and use regex to determine if the note is a tracking number. If it is it gets added using the tracking number function:

```
add_action(
    'wp_insert_comment',
    function( int $comment_id, WP_Comment $comment ) {
        /**
         * Only order notes will contain shipping information for a product.
         */
        if ( 'order_note' !== $comment->comment_type ) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Match note contents to UPS tracking number format.
         * Regex taken from https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53619924.shtml
         */
        preg_match(
            '/\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d)\b/',
            $comment->comment_content,
            $matches
        );

        /**
         * Abort if the note is not a UPS tracking number.
         */
        if ( empty( $matches ) ) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Add tracking details with details number extracted from order note.
         */
        if ( function_exists( 'ast_insert_tracking_number' ) ) {
            ast_insert_tracking_number(
                $comment->comment_post_ID,
                $matches[0],
                'UPS',
                strtotime( $comment->comment_date_gmt ),
                1
            );
        }
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Comment: Ok awesome thanks, but where would I add this code exactly?

Comment: can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-custom-code-to-wordpress/